# Generating Encryption Keys from Biometric Fingerprint Templates

Tags: encryption, fingerprint, entropy, biometrics

How would one go about generating Encryption Keys from Biometric Fingerprint Templates extracted from a fingerprint using either Griaule SDK or DigitalPersona SDK or any other SDK that will return the fingerprint template in either ISO or ANSI fingerprint templates format? Is there a way one would do that using Fuzzy Extractors, Secure Sketch, Bio Hashing or any other approach? I will appreciate if anyone can show me how to go about this in any programming language? I intend to use the obtained Encryption Keys in encryption and decryption of data.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is "key derivation". This is a good question for crypto.stackexchange.com. Google "encryption key derivation" for examples of deriving encryption keys from various sources, such as PBKDF2 for which you should be able to find a good, reputable and well-tested API. (It's best not to invent your own crypto.) I would suggest HKDF (cf. [RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869)) but I don't know of a public API that implements this.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I did not even know crypto.stackexchange.com existed. I appreciate your help and the insight you have given me. I am gradually coming out of the woods.